# How to know which file on my flash drive is stopping me from ejecting safely?

Tags: windows-10, usb

How to know which file on my flash drive is stopping me from ejecting safely?

[image]

Windows 10 is my OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Windows creates event logs with event ID 225. You can use Powershell to see the events related to the USB Drive, along with which things are using the USB drive and what files are open. Use this:

```
Get-EventLog -Logname System | Where-object {$_.EventID -eq 225}
```

Comment: And if you want to inspect the live handles, you can use Sysinternals ProcessExplorer, it has a search handle function,

Comment: Where to type this command Get-EventLog -Logname System | Where-object {$_.EventID -eq 225}?

Comment: Type this on Powershell. Open start menu, then scroll down to W section, expand Windows powershell, and click Windows Powershell. Then copy and paste the command there.